# How to interpret regular URLs with react-router 2.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can i make react-router interpret regular urls:

```
<a href="https://thisWebApp.com/someSpecificRoute">Regular url</a>
```

to make redirect without page reload?

that was working absolutely fine in older version. I really don't understand, why it was taken out?